# Android Filesystem

Tags: java, android, filesystems, media

I've been trying to get this working, but I'm stumbling somewhere.

Here is the major source of the whole thing. And the logcat result...some is a bit redundant. I have "startingDirectory" above the onCreate, so I copied and removed the private...

```
String startingDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String directory = startingDirectory;
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) == false) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Media is not mounted.");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Loading File Directory.");
        Log.d(TAG, "Directory listing for " + directory);
        File path = new File(directory);
        //File path = new File(directory);
        if (path.isDirectory()) {
            if (path.canRead()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Readable directory");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Non-readable directory");
                if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Media is mounted");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Media is not mounted");
                }

            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Is not a directory.");
        }
    }
```

And here is the logcat of the whole thing...

`07-13 01:13:45.705 4361-4361/? D/MainActivity: Loading File Directory.
07-13 01:13:45.705 4361-4361/? D/MainActivity: Directory listing for /storage/emulated/0
07-13 01:13:45.705 4361-4361/? D/MainActivity: Non-readable directory
07-13 01:13:45.706 4361-4361/? D/MainActivity: Media is mounted`

I'm trying to get the directory structure of current directory (staringDirectory) and place into an class...but it doesn't seem to stay from non-readable

Comment: I wasn't adding file permissions, even though in the manifest, I have them allowed. Have to love Android!!

+1'd you anyway for helping

Answer (score 0):

This is my permitFileAcess method using setWritable and setReadable method of java.io.File class whenever I modify some file and directory's permission.
Well, I still have got a message but it works for me

```
public static void permitFileAcess(final File file) {
        if (!file.setWritable(true, true)) {
            log.e(new Object[] { "Could not set Writable permissions" });
        }
        if (!file.setReadable(true, true)) {
            log.e(new Object[] { "Could not set Readable permissions" });
        }
        if (!file.setExecutable(true, true)) {
            log.e(new Object[] { "Could not set Executable permissions" });
        }
    }
```

So, if you want to create a file use it before the operation.

```
private static boolean createFile(File parent, String fileName, boolean createDir) {
        boolean returnValue = false;
        if (parent.isDirectory()) {
            File newFile = new File(parent.getAbsolutePath(), fileName);
            permitFileAcess(newFile);
            if (createDir) {
                returnValue = newFile.mkdir();
            } else {
                try {
                    returnValue = newFile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to retrieve all of the files and directories in a specific dir. To make a simple file file manager. If I don't SEE the file, I wouldn't know which one to load in.